# Deploy a ASPNETAPP on a docker container to a Windows VM using Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm currently using Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-premise) to deploy an ASP.NET App (CI-CD).

Is it possible to deploy this app to run via a docker container to a Windows VM?

i'm currently following the examples on this link on how to run an ASP.NET App on a docker container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1

How could i do the same by utilising Azure DevOps Server 2019 to do so.

basically most of not all of the resources/guides/how-to s saw are pointing deploy to the azure cloud or docker hub.

Comment: the automated build part  ends at the point where you upload the image to the ACR/docker hub. Then you need to have a powershell/bash script( remotely using VM agent ) that will pull the image from the ACR and start the containers in that VM.

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I'll try and explore this solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to deploy this app to run via a docker container to a Windows VM?

Yes it is possible, You will need to create a self-hosted agent on the Windows VM to which you deploy your app. You can just use powershell task to run `docker build` and `docker run` on the self-hosted agent without the need to upload the image to ACR/dockerhub.

Of course You can aslo upload the built image to ACR/dockerhub as @Aravind mentioned. And have a powershell task that pull the image.

The main idea is to use a powershell task to run docker command on the agent hosted on the Windows VM. You can refer to below steps.

1,create a self-hosted agent. Please check the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops).

2,create a build pipeline.
[Here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition) is an example to create a yaml pipeline.
[Here](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/) is an example to create a classic UI pipelie.

3, Customize your build pipeline, Use a single powershell task to run docker build and docker run command as described in [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1). (You can also use [docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) to build and push image to ARC/Dockerhub, and then use powershell task to pull and run the image as @Aravind mentioned.)

```
steps:

- powershell: |
   docker build -t aspnetapp .
   docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample aspnetapp

  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

Noted: please make sure docker is installed on the Windows VM(the powershell task will invoke the docker cli installed on the VM). And choose the self-hosted agent(hosted on Windows VM) to run your pipeline by choosing the [agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pool) where the self-hosted agent resides(the agent pool that includes the self-hosted agent is decided at the creation of the agent.)